# Meteor method callback loop, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, meteor

I've been looking at this for awhile and I'm pretty sure it has something to do with an infinite callback loop.

I have a method that returns an integer from a collection called Sessions. Here are my methods:

```
Meteor.methods({

      going: function(sessionsId) {
        return Sessions.update(sessionsId, {$addToSet: {participants: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {slots:-1}});  
      },

      retract: function(sessionsId) {
        return Sessions.update(sessionsId, {$pull: {participants: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {slots:1}});  
      },

      sessionFull: function(sessionsId) {
        var session = Sessions.findOne({_id:sessionsId});
        console.log("gets here");
        return session.slots;
      }
    });
```

Then in my client I have:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Template.hello.sessions = function () {
        return Sessions.find();
      };

      Template.session.this_info = function () {
        return this._id;
      };  

      Template.session.isGoing = function() {
        var session = Sessions.find({_id:this._id, participants:Meteor.userId()}).count();
        if (session > 0) return true;
        else return false;
      };

      Template.session.sessionFull = function() {
        if (this.slots === 0) return true;
        else return false;
      };

      Template.session.slotsMethod = function () {
        Meteor.call('sessionFull',this._id, function(error, slots) {
          Session.set("slots",slots);
        });
        return Session.get("slots");
      };

      Template.session.events({
        'click input.going' : function () {
         //Sessions.update(this._id, {$inc: {slots: -1}}); 
         Meteor.call('going', this._id, function(error, updated) {
           if (error)
             return alert(error.reason);
         });
        },

        'click input.retract' : function () {
          Meteor.call('retract', this._id, function(error, removed) {
            if (error)
              return alert(error.reason);
          });
        }
      });
```

So I basically have a couple buttons that will increase or decrease the slots field and I want to have a method that will return what the slots field contains. Here is my template:

```
      {{#each sessions}}
        {{> session}}
      {{/each}}

    <template name="session">
    <br>
    {{date_time}}, {{duration}}
    {{#if isGoing}}
      <input type="button" class="retract" value="not going/give slot" />
    {{else}}
      {{#if sessionFull}}
        <h1>SORRY SESSION FULL</h1>
      {{else}} 
        <input type="button" class="going" value="going/subract slot" />
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
    {{participants}},{{sessionFull}},{{this_info}}
    </template>
```

If I try to add the Template.session.slotsMethod to my template (which calls the sessionFull Meteor method) I get an infinite loop, as in, it will display a rapidly changing integer for each session.

Am I doing something wrong?? Can't figure it out, I think it has something to with callbacks/async/sync but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `Template.session.slotsMethod` will cause an infinite loop since [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) is reactive.

This is what happens:

- Whenever Session.get("slots") changes, `Template.session.slotsMethod` will be called because its dependent on `Session.get("slots")`.
- However, `Template.session.slotsMethod` itself is also updating the value of `Session.get("slots")` so the process starts all over again.

Not quite sure when you want `Template.session.slotsMethod` to be run, but you probably want to break it up into two pieces, something like:

```
Template.session.getSlots = function () {
  return Session.get("slots");
};
```

and

```
Meteor.call('sessionFull',this._id, function(error, slots) {
  Session.set("slots",slots);
});
```

needs to go wherever/whenever you need to do the `sessionFull` check, perhaps in `Template.session.rendered`?

Comment: ahh I get it, basically every session loop is sharing the same slots session variable... (obviously my variable name selection wasn't very good considering session is a Meteor variable too).